# How to run my code each and everytime on event based triggering

Tags: c#, api, unit-testing, visual-studio-2019, web-api-testing

I've a code in vs-2019, for unit testing with c# and Nunit framework. What I need to do is  to trigger this code using a queue message, everytime when the queue got a new message. How can I do that?? There are suggestions like azure Monitor and azure functions. If thats the case how can I incorporate anyone of them with my code. And I can't post my project here and really sorry for that. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One of the workarounds is to add reference of your project to Azure Functions.
Here is the sample code:

**QueueTrigger.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

namespace DotNet
{
    public static class QueueTrigger
    {
        public class Message : TableEntity
        {
            public string Text { get; set; }
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public async static Task RunAsync([QueueTrigger("myqueue-items", Connection = "connectionString")]string myQueueItem, [Table("MyTable", Connection = "connectionString")]IAsyncCollector<Message> messages, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
            var message = new Message();
            message.PartitionKey = "1";
            message.RowKey = "2";
            message.Text = myQueueItem;
            await messages.AddAsync(message);
        }
    }
}
```

**QueueTriggerTest.cs**

```
using FunctionTestHelper;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static DotNet.QueueTrigger;

namespace DotNet.Test
{
    [TestClass]
    public class QueueTriggerTest : FunctionTestHelper.FunctionTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public async Task Recieve_Queue_And_Emit_To_Table()
        {
            var col = new AsyncCollector<Message>();
            var json = "{\"name\": \"ushio\"}";
            await DotNet.QueueTrigger.RunAsync(json, col, log);
            Assert.AreEqual(json, col.Items[0].Text);

        }
    }
}
```

While coming to Azure Monitor you can directly configure Application Insights from your Visual Studio and then monitor the same from Azure Monitor in the portal.

**REFERENCES**

1. [Monitor Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring)
2. [Unit testing sample for Azure Functions](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/functions-unittesting-sample)